# Shared http session lifetime

Tags: session, identity, web-development-server

We have several web applications using the same identity provider (which we also manage), most of them (including identity provider) are using .NET core.
Requirement is that if user is logged in in two or more applications at the same time (in one browser), and is actively using one app, it automatically extends the session lifetime in **all** of the applications.

So while he's using at least one application, he doesn't get logged out of neither of them. Which is another requirement: auto-logout after certain time of inactivity (this part is easy of course)

I thought of using Redis server to manage this shared session lifetime, using SessionId that each app would receive from identity server via claims. So each time user does some action, backend contacts Redis and check if user's session is still active and extend the session lifetime if it is. Logout user if it's not.

Problem is, applications are not allowed to access this Redis server directly (security reasons). So I thought of adding a separate web service for these apps to contact using standard HTTP endpoint. So basically just a middleman between Redis and web app.

Is there any better way to do it? Not sure how common of a requirement is this.

Answer (score 0):

Redis usually belongs in the Distributed cache, which means that it is located on another server farm. Therefore, your application has restrictions because it is not allowed to access an external server.
If your application is under development or if it is still in the growth phase my recommendation is to use **InMemory cache** or consider **[response caching middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-5.0)**.
Also, these are very small amounts of data, and if you are going to store only that in the cache for a start you would definitely consider **InMemory**.

Of course, I understand your need for a Redis and that is it:

1. Is coherent (consistent) across requests to multiple servers.
2. Survives server restarts and app deployments. And that's because
   your cache is usually in a different location (e.g. Azure)
3. Doesn't use local memory.
4. Is scalable
5. etc.

For larger applications Consider replacing InMemory cache with the **[Distributed memory cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0#distributed-memory-cache)**. It is mostly similar to the InMemory cache because both the InMemory and the Distributed cache are located on the server farm where the application was run. Only the InMemory cache requires a sticky session, and the **Distributed memory cache** does not.